# Sticky Shrinknav (building block) not working on mobile

Tags: html, css, zurb-foundation

I've been working on a simple website for the past few days using Foundation and Spring Boot. I was looking for different ways to show the top menu and came across http://foundation.zurb.com/building-blocks/blocks/sticky-shrinknav.html.

I managed to implement it without issues, and it works fine when I view it on my computer no matter what size the screen is. However, when I open it on my phone, the menu is just barely visible on the right side of the screen, only showing the first option of the menu. A picture of what it looks like; https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nt18m.jpg. This is a picture what it looks like in Firefox using the responsive design mode: https://i.stack.imgur.com/2o5qm.jpg

I did combine it with a style from a different header, but that isn't causing the issue since when I implement it in the exact same way as in the building block, it still happens on my phone.

The code I'm using can be found below:

HTML:

```
<header class="sticky-shrinknav-header">
    <div class="sticky-shrinknav-header-title">
        <img src="/../assets/logo.png" style="height: 70%"/>
        <h1>Name</h1>
    </div>
    <ul class="menu align-center header-subnav">
        <li><a class="is-active" href="/">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="/about">About</a></li>
        <li><a href="/apply">Apply</a></li>
        <li><a href="/feed">Feed</a></li>
    </ul>
</header>
```

CSS:

```
body {
    padding-top: 330px;
}

.header-subnav li {
    float: none;
    display: inline-block;
}

.header-subnav li a {
    padding: 0.9rem 1rem;
    font-size: 0.75rem;
    color: #ffe;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    display: block;
    font-weight: bold;
    letter-spacing: 1px;
    transition: all 0.35s ease-in-out;
}

.header-subnav li a.is-active {
    background: rgba(250, 250, 250, 0.15);
}

.header-subnav li a:hover {
    background: rgba(250, 250, 250, 0.15);
    transition: all 0.35s ease-in-out;
}

.header-subnav {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 100%;
    transition: all 0.5s ease;
}

.sticky-shrinknav-header-title {
    transition: all 0.3s ease;
    position: relative;
    -webkit-transform: translateY(-1.875rem);
    -ms-transform: translateY(-1.875rem);
    transform: translateY(-1.875rem);
    margin-bottom: 0;
    color: #E6E8EB;
    height: 75%;
}

.sticky-shrinknav-header {
    width: 100%;
    height: 300px;
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: flex;
    -webkit-align-items: center;
    -ms-flex-align: center;
    align-items: center;
    -webkit-justify-content: center;
    -ms-flex-pack: center;
    justify-content: center;
    background-color: #2F343F;
    text-align: center;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    transition: all 0.5s ease;
    z-index: 999999;
}

body.sticky-shrinknav-wrapper {
    padding-top: 130px;
}

body.sticky-shrinknav-wrapper .sticky-shrinknav-header {
    height: 3.75rem;
    background-color: #404552;
}

body.sticky-shrinknav-wrapper .sticky-shrinknav-header .sticky-shrinknav-header-title {
    -webkit-transform: scale(0);
    -ms-transform: scale(0);
    transform: scale(0);
    transition: all 0.3s ease;
}
```

JS:

```
$(document).foundation();
$(function() {
    $(window).scroll(function() {
        var winTop = $(window).scrollTop();
        if (winTop >= 30) {
            $("body").addClass("sticky-shrinknav-wrapper");
        } else{
            $("body").removeClass("sticky-shrinknav-wrapper");
        }
    });
});
```

Any help is greatly appreciated!

**EDIT: this seems to only be a problem on Apple devices.**

Comment: Can you create a codepen or fiddle for this?

Comment: Never did that, but I tried; https://codepen.io/anon/pen/EmRdag